# How to transfer selected data from one page to another page in angular/ts?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

This is my Main Page
[image]
I want to redirect to this page
[image]

I want to redirect to the other page by clicking the Last 1 Day button and have the date filter and ItemId values selected on the other page.

Comment: Q: So you want an action in one page (e.g. a button press) to invoke another action in a different page, and pass the relevant data to the new page, correct?  You have several alternatives.  I would probably consider this one first: [Pass data from parent to child with input binding](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data along routes with `params` and read those params at destination component's `ngOnInit`.

You could also do an `observable` that continually emits those data so other components could read them.

Really depends on your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use input variables to input data through html, but I find a shared service to be the cleanest way to handle it. Services are singleton classes where you can store global data that can be accessed through dependency injection.

You can make a service specifically for this component, generate it with `ng g service file-path/service-name`. Probably best to put it in the same directory as your component.

Add your data and set some default values, or just leave them undefined.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyComponentService {
  selectedId?: number;
  startDate = '';
  endDate = '';
}
```

Inject the service into the component where you want to set values, the 'Main Page' in your case. Set the values according to your specific case.

```js
export class MainPageComponent {
  constructor(private myCompService: MyComponentService) {}

  setSelectedId(id: number) {
    this.myCompService.selectedId = id;
  }

  setDates(startDate: string, endDate: string) {
    this.myCompService.startDate = startDate;
    this.myCompService.endDate = endDate;
  }
}
```

Inject the service into the component that will use the values.

```js
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(public myCompService: MyComponentService) {
}
```

```html
<input type="number" [value]="myCompService.selectedId" />
<input type="date" [value]="myCompService.startDate" />
<input type="date" [value]="myCompService.endDate" />
```

---

You can also make getters and setters to use the data as if they were local variables.

```js
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private myCompService: MyComponentService) {}

  get selectedId() {
    return this.myCompService.selectedId;
  }

  set selectedId(id: number | undefined) {
    this.myCompService.selectedId = id;
  }

  get startDate() {
    return this.myCompService.startDate;
  }

  set startDate(date: string) {
    this.myCompService.startDate = date;
  }
  
  get endDate() {
    return this.myCompService.endDate;
  }

  set endDate(date: string) {
    this.myCompService.startDate = date;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" [value]="selectedId" />
<input type="date" [value]="startDate" />
<input type="date" [value]="endDate" />
```